# How to pass a variabile of the MATLAB's workspace to Simulink's model?

Tags: matlab, function, class, variables, simulink

I have the following class

```
classdef window < matlab.apps.AppBase
   ...
   function app = window
      % Construct app
   end
   ...
   properties (Access = public)
      rf = @f;
   end
   ...
   function f(app)
      % do something
   end
   ...
end
```

I'm able to call `f` from the MATLAB's workspace using the command `a.rf(a)`, where `a` is the variable of the MATLAB's workspace created by `a = window`. Now I would like to call `a.rf(a)` from within a Simulink's model. I was thinking to share the variable `a` with the Simulink's model, but

1. I don't know how to share that variable with a certain Simulink's block (and Simulink's model in general)
2. Which Simulink's block do I choose to execute `a.rf(a)` ? And how can I implement it (step by step) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot bring this class variable into Simulink. You should look for ways to call all your MATLAB code from Simulink. See if the techniques described at http://blogs.mathworks.com/simulink/2010/07/18/including-matlab-code-in-a-simulation/ help you.

Comment: Thank you for the great link! In few words, my class `window` contains several instructions for the control of the Simulink model itself. This class also defines and uses graphical objects. So, I have to include all of my class in a S-function block, right ?

Comment: Instead, Could I do the following workaround ? A Simulink's block in my model execute an m-function file (or script). This m-function file (or script) run in the MATLAB's workspace, so it can see the variable `a`. If I can do this, which block for the execution of the above function (or script) can I use in Simulink ?

Comment: I made the steps above. Even if I use the sequence `coder.extrinsic('evalin'); ra = evalin('base', 'a'); ra.f(ra);` in the m-function file, Simulink gives me the error `Attempt to extract field 'f' from 'mxArray'`. I read something about this error. Someone fix this problem with a "pre-declaration" of `ra`, or something like that. But I don't know ho to "pre-declare" the variable `ra`. So, how can I solve the latest problem ?

Comment: You should put your entire code in an external function. Then call this function using extrinsic declaration. Additionally pre-initialize the output of your function so that it will converted from mxarray to the data type you need. Pre-initialize is just filling a variable with zeros of correct data type and size before assigning the output from your function.